# Can I access my website from Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to develop a website where I can see the homepage as it is from Django admin panel. The reason I want that is I want to edit the name of the static content like 'Home' to 'All' along with the change of slide show picture. In summary, I want to change the website layout from Django admin panel that is not accessible to users. Is that possible? I just want an idea of how to implement the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static texts you can change in admin panel with different modules:
for example `django-rosetta` or my own library `Django-tof`. https://github.com/wP-soft-GmbH/django-tof

But in your case, i think, you want to made something more.

For this case you can use `django-flat-pages`, already included in Django, if you have a static web-page.
you can edit every element on the page and after save, you can see it on the front.

if you really want to change the django templates, which you use in your views, you can create a simple template editor in the admin panel based on a widget like `django-Ckeditor`.